# Android Listview multiple items selected

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to populate an arraylist into a list view using a custom adapter. The data is being retreived from an SQLite database and this is all working fine. The problem I am having is that I need to be able to select a number of different entries in the list and take the data to create a PDF report.

I have managed to get the selection working to a point, but the problem is that when I select an item in the list, the third item after and then every third item is also selected. The code I am using to populate the list view is:

```
resultsView.setChoiceMode(resultsView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
final ArrayList<Results> resultsList = (ArrayList<Results>) srsDB.getReulstByMeter(CurrentUser.currentMeter.getID());
final ResultsAdapter adapter = new ResultsAdapter(getActivity(),resultsList);
resultsView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have tried to use and onItemClickListener to change the background of the selected item using the following:

```
                resultsView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    resultsView.setSelection(position);
                    Log.i("Selectio", "" + position);
                    view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
                    if(view.isSelected()){ 
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    } else {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            });
```

The ResultsAdapter code is shown here:

```
public class ResultsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Results>{

private SRSDatabase srsDB;
private Meters meter;
private Customers customer;
private int mItemIndex = -1;
private int pos;

public ResultsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Results> results) {
    super(context, R.layout.result_row, results);
    srsDB = new SRSDatabase(context);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Results result = getItem(position);
    pos = position;


    if(convertView==null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.result_row,parent, false);
        convertView.setSelected(false);
    }

    //Look up view for data population
    TextView custName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customerNameRes);
    TextView testDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resultDate);
    TextView meterSN = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.meterResSN);
    TextView meterConst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.meterResConst);
    TextView meterRating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.meterResRat);
    TextView vA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resVa);
    TextView vB = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resVb);
    TextView vC = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resVc);
    TextView iA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resIa);
    TextView iB = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resIb);
    TextView iC = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resIc);
    TextView tA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resTa);
    TextView tB = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resTb);
    TextView tC = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resTc);
    TextView frequency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resFreq);
    TextView error = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resError);

    //Populate the data into the template using the data object
    custName.setText(srsDB.getCustomerByID(result.getCustomerID()).getCustomer());
    testDate.setText("" + result.getDate());
    meter = srsDB.getMeterByID(result.getMeterID());
    meterSN.setText("" +  result.getID());
    meterConst.setText("" + meter.getConstant());
    meterRating.setText("" + meter.getRating());
    vA.setText("" + result.getVA());
    vB.setText("" + result.getVB());
    vC.setText("" + result.getVC());
    iA.setText("" + result.getIA());
    iB.setText("" + result.getIB());
    iC.setText("" + result.getIC());
    tA.setText("" + result.getThetaA());
    tB.setText("" + result.getThetaB());
    tC.setText("" + result.getThetaC());
    frequency.setText("" + result.getFrequency());
    error.setText("" + result.getError());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

I have read around and tried multiple different things but am struggling to get anything working the way that I want to. Does anyone have any advise or tips on what I may have done wrong.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following:

1. Add a `boolean` flag `isSelected` in `Results` class, set it as `false` by default. This flag will be used to set background color.
2. Set background color In `getView()` of `ResultsAdapter` on the bases of `isSelected` flag.
3. Toggle the value of `isSelected` and set Background color in `onItemClick()`.

Comment: Thats great, thank you for you help. Now I only have the item that I want selected.

Comment: I can't because I only have 3 rep. Need 15 to do that and only joined the other day. I tried when you replied.